# Alignments in html signature

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I really hope you can help as I'm going crazy trying to figure out how I can make this signature the way I want.

Basically, I would like the logo to be aligned at the top with the text,
and the bottom image to be left aligned, starting underneath the logo (and not underneath the text).

**Note:** This `html` is for email, so I can't using `css`.

Here is a visual of what I have (and want) and the code :[image]

```html
<table id="sig" style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 82px; line-height: 18px; margin: 6px 0; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px #15345B dotted; border-bottom: 1px #3d3d3d dotted; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; color: #3d3d3d;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
            <a href="http://www.txxxxk.fr" title="www.txxxxk.fr">
                <img src="http://www.txxxxk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/defweb_logotaldeak-red3.png" alt="Txxxxk" style="float: left; padding: 6px 20px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
            <span style="font-size: 12px"><strong style="color: #000000; letter-spacing: 1px">Oxxxxxx xxxxxy</strong>, CEO</span><br>
            <strong style="color: #d80f0f; letter-spacing: 1px">TxxxxK</strong><br>
            e: <a href="mailto:oxxxxx@txxxxxk.fr" title="oxxxxx@txxxxk.fr" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000">oxxxxx@txxxxxk.fr </a>| s: <a href="http://www.txxxxxk.fr" title="www.txxxxxk.fr" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000">www.txxxxxk.fr </a>
            <br>
            t.: 0xxxxxxxx0 | m.: 0xxxxxx5<br>
            5 xxxxxx - 6xxxxx Bxxxx<br>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/Txxxxk">
                <img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/t.png" alt="Twitter" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/Txxxxk">
                <img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/f.png" alt="Facebook" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
            <a href="http://linkedin.com/company/txxxxk">
                <img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/l.png" alt="Linked In" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a><br />
            <a href="http://www.txxxxk.fr">
                <img src="http://www.txxxxk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/banner-signature-2016.png" alt="Vxxxxxt" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you change your `html`? Also, It is highly recommended that you avoid using tables for layout.

Comment: @MoshFeu I think it's for an email signature which requires code from the 90s - divs aren't compatible with email clients

Comment: yes indeed @TT120, it is an email signature :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table id="sig" style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 82px; line-height: 18px; margin: 6px 0; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px #15345B dotted; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; color: #3d3d3d;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
            <a href="http://www.txxxxk.fr" title="www.txxxxk.fr">
                <img src="http://www.txxxxk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/defweb_logotaldeak-red3.png" alt="Txxxxk" style="float: left; padding: 6px 20px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
            <span style="font-size: 12px"><strong style="color: #000000; letter-spacing: 1px">Oxxxxxx xxxxxy</strong>, CEO</span><br>
            <strong style="color: #d80f0f; letter-spacing: 1px">TxxxxK</strong><br>
            e: <a href="mailto:oxxxxx@txxxxxk.fr" title="oxxxxx@txxxxk.fr" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000">oxxxxx@txxxxxk.fr </a>| s: <a href="http://www.txxxxxk.fr" title="www.txxxxxk.fr" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000">www.txxxxxk.fr </a>
            <br>
            t.: 0xxxxxxxx0 | m.: 0xxxxxx5<br>
            5 xxxxxx - 6xxxxx Bxxxx<br>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/Txxxxk">
                <img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/t.png" alt="Twitter" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/Txxxxk">
                <img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/f.png" alt="Facebook" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
            <a href="http://linkedin.com/company/txxxxk">
                <img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/l.png" alt="Linked In" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="border-bottom: 1px #3d3d3d dotted; margin: 0px 0 6px; min-width: 960px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><a href="http://www.txxxxk.fr">
            <img src="http://www.txxxxk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/banner-signature-2016.png" alt="Vxxxxxt" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7du19ko/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick, just place the bottom content on its own row.

```html
<table id="sig" style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 82px; line-height: 18px; margin: 6px 0; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px #15345B dotted; border-bottom: 1px #3d3d3d dotted; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; color: #3d3d3d; " >
<tr>
<td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0" >
    <a href="http://www.txxxxk.fr" title="www.txxxxk.fr"><img src="http://www.txxxxk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/defweb_logotaldeak-red3.png" alt="Txxxxk" style="float: left; padding: 6px 20px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
</td>
<td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
    <span style="font-size:12px"><strong style="color: #000000; letter-spacing: 1px">Oxxxxxx xxxxxy</strong>, CEO</span><br>
    <strong style="color: #d80f0f;letter-spacing: 1px">TxxxxK</strong><br>
    e: <a href="mailto:oxxxxx@txxxxxk.fr" title="oxxxxx@txxxxk.fr" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;color:#000000">oxxxxx@txxxxxk.fr </a> | s: <a href="http://www.txxxxxk.fr" title="www.txxxxxk.fr" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;color:#000000">www.txxxxxk.fr </a><br> 
t.: 0xxxxxxxx0 | m.: 0xxxxxx5<br>
    5 xxxxxx - 6xxxxx Bxxxx<br> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="http://twitter.com/Txxxxk"><img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/t.png" alt="Twitter" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
<a href="http://facebook.com/Txxxxk"><img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/f.png" alt="Facebook" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
<a href="http://linkedin.com/company/txxxxk"><img src="https://img.newoldstamp.com/s/d/l.png" alt="Linked In" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a><br />
  
<a href="http://www.txxxxk.fr"><img src="http://www.txxxxk.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/banner-signature-2016.png" alt="Vxxxxxt" style="float: left; margin: 2px 4px 0 0; border: none;"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time. your answer was almost perfect. i just wanted to keep the social network images below the text, so i went with Arun's code. but you both rock !!

Comment: No problem, glad we could help, sorry I was a little off on what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're using one table row for an appearance that needs two rows, also you need two td tags in the first tr to get the logo and text next to each other:

think of it like:

< ROW (TR) >

```
 < DATA (TD)>    < DATA (TD) >
```

< / ROW (TR) >

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><!-- logo goes here --></td>
        <td><!-- contact info goes here --></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><!-- Banner goes here --></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: definitely makes more sense now. thanks for the clarification !!

Comment: @Grace,  no worries :)